# Loop through folder, delete all shortcuts and make new ones

Tags: powershell

So what my powershell script does currently is it asks for path, name of new folder and what the old one was and then it copies the old file contents and puts them in the new one.
What i want after that is to delete all shortcuts and make new ones with target of the exe in new folder and the path or "start in" to be the location of the exe

What code i have currently:

```
$Location = Read-Host -Prompt 'User writes loc'
Set-Location -Path $Location
$oldname = Read-Host -Prompt 'User writes old file name'
$newname = Read-Host -Prompt 'User writes new file name'
Copy-Item -Path "$Location\$oldname" -Destination "$Location\$newname" -Recurse

$folder = "$Location\$newname"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Include *.lnk -File -Recurse

//Here i now want to delete all the shortcuts it found, tried this 2 ways 
//both dont work (inside or outside the loop)
Get-ChildItem  -Recursive *.lnk | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName }
Remove-Item '$folder\*' -Recurse -Include *.lnk

ForEach($file in $files){ 
//Then have path set to location where it found the shortcut/exe 
//and then target the exe (idk how to get "link") 
    New-Item -ItemType SymbolicLink -Path "Link" -Target $file
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: There is no `-Recursive` parameter for `Get-ChildItem`. For link removal, try: `Get-ChildItem $Folder *.lnk -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf` to ensure you're finding your files. Then try without the `-WhatIf` parameter.

Comment: To create/modify `.lnk` shortcut files, you use the `wscript.shell` COM object. `$NewShortcut = (New-Object -com wscript.shell).CreateShortcut("C:\Path\To\File.lnk")`